# Where to ask opinion-based questions?

Tags: discussion

I know that the various stackexchange sites are primarily Q&A, and any subjective questions should be kept in chat. But the EE stackexchange chat is kind of dead, and I have some questions on why people use EE a certain way (solely to further my own learning - compare and contrast with how I've learned to do things / done things for years.) Is there another place I could ask these, besides in chat?

For instance:
* I wanted to ask about why people build templates with so many levels of includes (an embed within another embed within a template, for example) instead of flattening things out a bit.
* I wanted to ask why people use things like SEO Lite or NSM Meta, instead of creating the keyword and description variables for each channel

I suspect that the answer to most of my questions is going to boil down to "preference" or "workstyle", but I'm honestly interested in discussing the pros and cons of various techniques, server load versus ease of maintenance, and I'm not entirely sure if EE.SE.com has a place to do that that actually gets some visits.

...halp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the weekly [EE Help Chat](http://eeinsider.com/ee-help-chat) would be a great place for these kinds of questions.

But having said that, I think "What is the advantage to using several embeds vs putting all of your code in each template?", or "What is the advantage of using an SEO/Metadata add-on vs using standard EE fields?" are both perfectly suitable EESE questions.

Comment: I didn't know that this chat existed!! Thanks! And as soon as I'm a little less frantic, I'll post those others in the main EESE. (The last one sounded a bit opinion-y, so I wasn't sure if it was suitable or not.)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Derek - if you can phrase the questions in an objective way, then they will be perfectly fine here. Often it's just a case of asking it in a way that's not too open ended.

Note that it's not just an arbitrary rule against opinion-based questions - the main problem is if the question turns into a discussion, which really doesn't fit with the "upvote" system used here. If people start trying to mention each other in their answers, and asking follow up questions, there is no where to respond, and it makes the whole discussion very hard to follow once the answers get out of order.

That said, I wish there was a sort of a "discussion" area of EESE. I think it would be a little confusing for people though to know where to ask which questions. Anyway, we are at the mercy of the platform here - we try to be the best problem solving place for EE, and let other sites fill the gaps elsewhere. I think the EE help chat is one of those resources. There is also the official EL forums, Twitter, Reddit etc which you could try.

Answer (score 0):

I had absolutely no clue about the existence of EE StackExchange Chat. Maybe that's part of the reason it is dead?